Can not find HTTP Headers sent from QGIS to GeoServer (Koop)
I'm setting HTTP Headers in QGIS:

I expected "x-my-extra-info" to show up in the request headers in Koop (an Express app). However, I've console logged the headers (and rawHeaders) and don't see them. Am I looking in the wrong place, or is there some trick involved?
Using:
QGIS version
3.34.4-Prizren
QGIS code revision
1e052ed1f5e

It seems that you are using ArcGIS REST connection. Is that correct?

That is correct. This routes to a Koop instance (which is where I want to access the extra header)

I tested putting a remote server that just logs requests (webhook.site) into a QGIS ArcGIS REST Server connection, included the custom header  "x-my-extra-info" "some extra info etc..." and that header and value got logged correctly.  Maybe it's a Koop issue, I dont know, so can't answer.

An interesting development is that if I setup the connection as WMS, the header is sent and logged in Koop (even though, as expected, QGIS can't parse the response). So, I don't think it's Koop, but it could be something within our cluster. Or perhaps it's related to the version of QGIS I'm using (3.34.4-Prizren, rev 1e052ed1f5e)???
